# Lien connection issue while trying to shut down the project

Tags: shutdown, dialogflow-cx

While trying to shut down the project I receive notification that Project has one or more liens. Lien origin is Dialogflow. I was asked to delete the agent. I have done so two days ago but system can still see the lien and does not allow me to shut the project down. Following origin of lien is not helping, there is nothing behind it.

Answer (score 0):

If the agent has been deleted and lien error occurred, you may remove the lien as described at https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-liens#removing_liens_from_a_project.

Once the lien is deleted, you should be able to shut down the project.

If there's still an error in removing liens, you can provide screenshots of the error or error messages.